# Grails splitting the application

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

Is there any advantages or any available pattern where in we create just the Domain classes and jar it, to be used in different grails applications applicable.

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach for reusing Grails artifacts (domain classes, controllers, etc.) is to create a plugin, not a jar file. See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/12.%20Plug-ins.html